# Birthday probability of $k$ people and $n$ days a year such that at least $2$ people have the same bday

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations, birthday

A certain planet has n days in one year. What is the probability that among $k$ people on that planet there are (at least) two who share their birthday?

My answer to this practice question is:
There are $N^k$ probabilities/cases in total. We now have to count the favorable/conditional cases. There are ${n}\choose{k}$ ways to select no two people having birthday on the same day. The probability is then $p=1-\frac{{n}\choose{k}}{N^k}$.

But I'm sure the problem is more complicated than that...

Comment: Hi James, please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: got it thankss!

Comment: Have you tried applying pigeon-hole principle in this problem ?

Comment: Apart from your mixing $N$ and $n$, it is no more complicated than that. Test it with $n=365$ and $k=23$ and see if you get a probability just over $0.5$. If $0 \lt n\lt k$ you can take ${n \choose k}=0$ so the probability is $1$ in that case

Comment: what is the difference between big N and small n?

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Answer (score 1):

While $k>n$, it is obviously a $100$ percent chance, so we shall not consider a case.  So, as the answer says, the number of undesired outcomes is $({n\atop k})$, because we are choosing $k$ different days from $n$ to ensure that there is no overlapping of birthdays.  Note the importance of the world different, as it means that there are $k$, and only $k$ days to have the birthdays, or else there would be overlaps.

Then I presume the rest would be easily understandable, because it is just finding the fraction of possible ways over the total ways.

Comment: so is my answer incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you can accept this answer and upvote

Comment: I mean, the answer above is correct @jamesblack

Comment: That was my answer and I was just asking for a confirmation (because i thoguht that the answer is too easy) haha so my answer is good

Comment: you lied this was wring...not thee answer

Comment: I did not lie.  You were correct